# How to filter a list based on specify word in a search box

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I have a list with more than 20 columns and more than 1000 rows. I have called this list in sharepoint page.

Here I need to add a search box, where if I type a word "Oracle" in that search box the list has to get filtered in such a way that where ever the word Oracle is present it has to display all those rows.

I tried using Filters and Search Web parts but can't able to achieve it. Any idea.

Comment: which SharePoint version are you using? Sp2010? In SP2013 there is already a searchbox in each list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding and connecting a text filter webpart to your list page?

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-Filter-Web-Part-to-a-List-View-Web-Part-4f3f6c10-0a1b-479d-8b4d-c4f1bf49bb3f#bms1

Comment: In the above link they mentioned about List View Webpart, but in my sharepoint designer there is no such type of Webpart

Comment: this webpart is already added to your standard view

Comment: yes, it worked. Thanks for sharing your idea. Is it possible to highlight the search result text?

Comment: You're welcome. Inspect your search to results to see whether your keyword is wrapped by some element that you could style with css, otherwise you would need a jQuery plugin http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-text-highlighter-plugins/. You could implement both solutions by adding a script editor webpart above your filter webpart. In any case, if that text filter solution worked for you, please mark the answer as correct. Thanks!